# Add Chromcast Audio to Spotify on macOS

Tags: macos, audio, spotify, chromecast

My phone can cast Spotify to the Chromecast Audio I connected to the stereo. Spotify on my Macbook doesn't display this device. When I click the devices-button, I don't see the Chromecast Audio, so I cannot connect it. When I cast from the phone, the device suddenly appears in Spotify on the macbook.

**How can I add the Chromecast Audio device to the Spotify app on my Macbook?**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cast from macbook to the chromecast audio with spotify you will also need an ios, android or a chrome with spotify web logged in.

These are the steps.

First, in you computer open spotify and play some music.

[image]

**Chrome**

- Go to [Spotify Web](https://open.spotify.com)
- Login
- Select your cast device under the "Connect to a Device" menu

[image]

**Android/IOS**

Open Spotify in your mobile, it will prompt a message, press continue

[image]

After that in the mobile select the speaker

[image]

after that you will be able to select your chromecast

[image]

In conclusion, you will have the control from the macbook, but the mobile os will be the bridge between your computer and the chromecast.

Comment: Using the web site with google chrome is great option. Note, need to be off of  a VPN for it to work well.